# Get substring value after last occurrence of "_" in sql database

Tags: sql-server

I want to get value after last occurrence of "_" so I am using below approach and it is giving me "BSARST.G041720151200" which is correct.

Is their any better way of doing this or below approach is decent enough?

```
declare @var varchar(max)='\\IPC-NAS03.ads.aexp.com\US022868_E3\BatchFilings\BatchArchive\FIU2FINCEN_BSARST.G041720151200'
select right(@var,charindex('_',reverse(@var))-1)
```

Comment: The only alternative approach, I can think of, would be to use a string splinter which numbers the parts (e.g. [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2)), and then select the first row based on item number descending. That *might* be faster.

Comment: Can you give example in above case ?

Comment: you could use a non greedy regex that matches against  _ wild and then end of string.  Probably not faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only add a ***"fail-safe"***.  Notice the `+'_'`  this way it will not throw an error if no `_` is found

Example

```
select right(@var,charindex('_',reverse(@var)+'_')-1)
```

Or **NULL** the string if not found via `nullif()`

```
select right(@var,nullif(charindex('_',reverse(@var)),0)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments: *"The only alternative approach, I can think of, would be to use a string splinter which numbers the parts (e.g. [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2)), and then select the first row based on item number descending. That* might *be faster."*:

```
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT DS.Item,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber DESC) AS RN --PARTITION BY V.YourString?
    FROM (VALUES('\\IPC-NAS03.ads.aexp.com\US022868_E3\BatchFilings\BatchArchive\FIU2FINCEN_BSARST.G041720151200'))V(YourString)
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.YourString,'_') DS)
SELECT R.Item
FROM RNs R
WHERE R.RN = 1;
```

Comment: I can't believe this delimited split is faster than the 3 functions in the OP

Comment: I didn't say it would be, @Hogan . But we could test.